Laravel - How to set up Supabase as a file system?
I want to use Supabase as a filesystem so I can easily upload files to Supabase. I used this package (github.com/quix-labs/laravel-supabase-flysystem) to set it up and added the supabase block to the disks array in config/filesystems.php. However, I can't upload anything to Firebase - the method that actually uploads the file returns this error message: "Unable to write file at location: uploads/RQhhQkjeHerFo5f1OxUgU0LMa40Kulif52tUKzzM.png."
I'm not sure I've set everything up correctly. I have this config:
'supabase' => [
            'driver' => 'supabase',
            'key'    => env('SUPABASE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'), // Use a privileged key; read-only does not work
            'bucket' => env('SUPABASE_STORAGE_BUCKET'),
            'endpoint' => env('SUPABASE_STORAGE_ENDPOINT'),

            'url'      => null, // <- Automatically generated; change here if you are using a proxy

            'public'                      => true,  // Default to true
            'defaultUrlGeneration'        => null, // 'signed' | 'public' <- default depends on public

            'defaultUrlGenerationOptions' => [
                'download'  => false,
                'transform' => [],
            ],

            'signedUrlExpires' => 60 * 60 * 24, // 1 day <- default to 1 hour (3600)
        ],

I'm guessing the bucket is simply the name of the bucket (e.g. myapp-file-uploads) and the endpoint is the one specified in the storage settings.
The key is the bit I don't understand.  I don't know what "Use a privileged key; read-only does not work" means. I've tried the S3 key in the storage settings and the Project API keys in the API settings.
Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Did you add the values (SUPABASE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, SUPABASE_STORAGE_BUCKET, SUPABASE_STORAGE_ENDPOINT) into the .env file? Another  question is, are you using a library or package that adds support for Supabase to your Laravel installation. As far as I know that is not supported by Laravel out of the box and needs to be added. Also, please show us the code where you actually use the this driver to upload a file.

SUPABASE_STORAGE_ENDPOINT should be your project  URL (https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.supabase.co) and SUPABASE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY should be your service_role secret in Project API keys tab.

For anyone else seeing this question, note that Supabase has an S3-compatible protocol that is out for alpha testing, so technically speaking, you can use Laravel's S3 driver to connect to Supabase's Storage.
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/storage/s3/authentication?queryGroups=language&language=credentials#s3-access-keys
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/filesystem#amazon-s3-compatible-filesystems
